# converting Javascript array of properties into an object with correct ordering of properties

Tags: javascript

In my Javascript application, I have an array with few properties `var sampleArray = ["Number_Info", "Additional_Ids","Additional_Ids_2","_summary"];`Now I need to convert this array into an object containing properties in the same order, as shown below :

```
var sampleObject = {
    "Number_Info" : {}, 
    "Additional_Ids" : {},
    "Additional_Ids_2" : {},
    "_summary" : {}
}
```

I tried the following  :

```
var orderingObj = {};
for(var i=0; i < sampleArray.length; i++ ){
orderingObj[sampleArray[i]] = {}
}
```

But here I am getting object properties in different order.

```
 var orderingObj = {
"Additional_Ids_2" : {},
"Additional_Ids" : {},
"Number_Info" : {},
 "_summary" : {}
};
```

How can I fix it? From earlier posts the solutions were there to sort by names but here I have a specific order in which I want to order my properties.

Comment: how does that matter?

Comment: Javascript can arrange object properties in alphabetical order. But in case of object, properties names order doesn't matter

Comment: I populate each of these properties values (in my question I have put empty objects) and display them on the front end, using for loop I am  iterating each of these properties and display them. I want these properties displayed on the front end should be as shown in the array properties order. Please let me know, if I need to give any further clarification on this.

Comment: `for(var key in orderingObj) console.log(key);` - I think you're getting confused by the behaviour of the developer console (which orders the displayed object alphabetically), and the enumeration order if you were to actually iterate over the object.